# Send localstorage variables to the next page

Tags: jquery, cordova, local-storage

I'm trying to develop an app with Jquery/phonegap. It's pretty much done, but one thing doesn't work when I make the APK. And that is the querystring I have used. Worked great in the browser but not as APK.

So instead I'm gonna try using localstorage.

I've got this code that outputs a list that it gets from my server. I want to be able to click on one of these to be passed to the arenaDetails.html page. And there you will only see data for that particular post in the db.

My question is. How would I pass all these to the next page. I know localstorage, but my question is more, what is the best way to get the id of the listview item someone clicks into localstorage and then send them to the right page? It's the dynamically created list that's causing me problems here.

my current code, using querystring:

```
var arenas;

$('#ListArenasPage').on('pageshow', function(event) {
        getarenaList();
});

function getarenaList() {
    var country = window.localStorage.getItem("country");
    $.getJSON(URL + 'getarenas.php?id=' + country, function(data) {
        $('#arenaList li').remove();
        arenas = data.items;
        $.each(arenas, function(index, arena) {
            $('#arenaList').append('<li><a href="arenaDetails.html?id=' + arena.id + '">' +
                    '<img src="pics/' + arena.picture + '"/>' +
                    '<h4>' + arena.arenaName + '</h4>' + '<p id="category">Club:' + arena.arenaClub + '</p>' +
                    '<p>Capacity:' + arena.arenaCapacity + '</p>' +
                    '<span class="ui-li-count">' + arena.id + '</span></a></li>');
        });
        $('#arenaList').listview('refresh');
    });
}
```

How do I get this, for example, (`window.localStorage.setItem("currentid", arena.id);`) to be set and then send the user to the correct page based on what specific listview item he or she pressed?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just through the arena.Id in the URL when switching pages and on the new page grab the Id and pull from db accordingly.

Comment: Yeah, that's how it works now. But it doesn't work on android when creating an APK. So instead of using that ?id= arena.id I have to change it to set a localstorage variable and then pass the user to the page. 

Thats where I'm stuck. Guess I'll need some click event or something? But I would need to use some `this` when the each function is looping the list out. I'm pretty new to jquery.

Comment: So html5 only or are you open to options? Because we can can get hack-a-licious with it.